# How to concat a where clause only if id is not null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a method which returns an ActiveRecord_Relation and I would like to concat a `where`clause if the id received in `params` is not null. Something like this

```
query.where(item_id: params[:item_id]) # only if params[:item_id] is not null.

query # only if params[:item_id] is null.
```

It would be perfect a query like the first one:

```
query.where(item_id: params[:item_id])
```

in which, a nil value invalidates the whole where instead of searching an item_id with nil id.

Of course I can do this using a conditional. But I would like to know if there is a rails way to do this. A one-liner or something

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a scope in your model - that's what they're for, to scope queries on models. Scopes *always* return a query, so you can do something like the following (assuming the model you're querying is called something like `Product`):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :by_item_id, -> (item_id) { where(item_id: item_id) if item_id }
end
```

Then you can call `Product.by_item_id(params[:item_id])`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing scope is one of the best thing if you would be repeating the query.
If not you can simply do:

```
query.where(item_id: params[:item_id]) if params[:item_id]
```

Comment: but with this solution, if params[:item_id] is nil, the whole query won't run. I would like to run just query if params[:item_id] is nil

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to use a scope, a one-liner can be accomplished with the `then` method:

```
query.then{|q| params[:item_id].blank? ? q : q.where(item_id: params[:item_id])}
```

##### Optional explanation

The value of `query` is passed to the block as `q`. The ternary statement determines whether to simply return the query `q` or concatenate the additional `where` clause. Then the return value of the block becomes the value of the overall expression.

This is conceptually equivalent to procedural code, like this:

```
q = query
if params[:item_id].blank?
  q
else
  q.where(item_id: params[:item_id])
end
```

The benefit of `then` is that it keep the code inline, and multiple `then`s can be concatenated together:

```
query.
  .then{|q| params[:item_id].blank? ? q : q.where(item_id: params[:item_id])}
  .then{|q| params[:item2_id].blank? ? q : q.where(item2_id: params[:item2_id])}
  .then{|q| params[:item3_id].blank? ? q : q.where(item3_id: params[:item3_id])}
```

`Object#then` became available in Ruby 2.6 and is an alias for `yield_self`, available since Ruby 2.5.